# Why does GKE Console list an internal LB as an external LB?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When I create a LoadBalancer like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webhook-event-source-service
  namespace: argo-events
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.196.xxx.xxx
  selector:
    controller: eventsource-controller
  ports:
  - port: 1212
    targetPort: 1212
    protocol: TCP
```

Why does the GKE Console list it as an "External Load Balancer"?

[image]

Comment: I would say StackOverflow is not the best place for such questions. If you consider this discrepancy a bug, you can report it via [Google's public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187225&template=1162610).

Comment: I admire your self-confidence. But my first reaction to such an observation (especially wrt to Google/K8s) is not "I found a bug" but "seems like I don't get it, yet". Hence my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, this problem has already been reported some time ago on Google's [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179694570) and it's currently under investigation:

> Problem you have encountered:
>
> I created a Deployment and a LoadBalancer Service as described in the
> [official
> docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing)
>
> Notice the LoadBalancer service is annotated with
> `networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"`
>
> What you expected to happen:
>
> I expected to see this service listed as  `Internal Load Balancer`  in
> the  `Services & Ingress`  view of the GCP console.
>
> Instead it is listed as an  `External Load Balancer`. (See attachment)
>
> Going to the specific load balancer in the  `Load Balancing`  view
> shows it as Internal.
>
> Steps to reproduce:
>
> Just follow the docs and head to the  `Services & Ingress`  view in
> the console.

And the answer from **GCP support**, confirming that they were also able to reproduce the issue and are analyzing it at the moment:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for reaching out.
>
> I've managed to reproduce the same scenario that you've included in
> your message.
>
> I forwarded this information to the Engineering team.
>
> Please follow this issue in case of any further updates.
>
> Best regards

So if you are interested in progressing on this issue, feel free to follow [this thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179694570) for further updates.